# Can't Access HTML Attribute in User Control Page Load

Tags: html, asp.net, pageload

I have a ASP.NET user control that has a div with runat="server".  When I try to access a div's class attribute initial page load I get a null exception error.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    container1.Attributes.Add("class", "Test")
End Sub
```

Comment: check to see if `Attributes` has a value, aka, is not null.

Comment: Dleh, the div is actually null.  I wonder if this has anything to do with the fact that this is nested in another user control.

Comment: that is probably the cause then. maybe try doing `FindControl("container1")` on the parent control

Answer (score 0):

If `container1` is in a child control then perhaps a property is needed on that child control that looks for a specific attr, it's neater than doing FindControl and will be less prone to errors